# Better then vs better than

Tags: word-usage

I frequently use *then* where I might should use *than*.

For example. My previous question was self-titled:

> Is pretty nice nicer then nice?

And was edited to:

> Is pretty nice nicer than nice?

Have not thought of it before other that it *sounds* OK and hence used it. Looking up the definition at for example Google I get:

1. at that time; at the time in question.
2. after that; next; afterwards.

Where neither fits as far as I can see, (perhaps 1.). Is it completely wrong to use *then* in this context?

---

Edit:

*Look in the dictionary*. OK, accept that, but:

Have a look at for example:

- [Cambridge example adverb, then](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/then)

  - We have a ​town ​house, a ​country ​cottage, and then there's ​our ​villa in Spain.
- [Common Errors in English Usage](http://public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/than.html), as in it is common?
- [Number of hits on web-search, e.g. Google, and their content](http://www.google.com/search?q=then%20vs%20than)

The amount of effort by numerous people and sources on the subject might suggest the issue is not *that obvious* in every case. This can obviously be interpreted in several ways in regards to causation.

The example from Cambridge is for instance one that throw me off a bit. (And similar cases *might* subconsciously have brought me to the dilemma I sometimes face when choosing between the two.)

But; hope I am on the right track now. Then is better used than than both when and then.

Comment: Yes, it's completely wrong to use *then* in this context.

Comment: **Then** could work if used in a **contrived** way with your original sentence: "Is pretty nice, nicer, **then** nice, the correct descending order of nice-ness?"

Comment: If you're comparing things, always use "than".

Comment: If you study, **then** some day you will know more **than** I do about English grammar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Then* and *than* have two different grammatical functions:

- ***[Then](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/then)*** (/ðen/) is an adverb and it is used to express a temporal relationship between two or more events (with the meaning of "next" or "after"), a cause - effect condition (as a synonymous of "as a result"), or to add some more details to a sentence (with the meaning of "in addition" or "moreover") :

  > • Let me ​finish this ​job, *then* we'll go. [time] 
  >   • If you ​plan the ​project well, *then* everything should ​fall into ​place. [~ "as a result"] 
  >   • Let's ​see - there were Mary, Jack, Greg and myself - *then* there were the ​children, Amy, John and Laura, ​plus the two ​dogs. [~ "in addition"]
- ***[Than](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/than)*** (/ðæn/ or /ðən/) is a conjunction and it's used in [comparative sentences](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/comparison-adjectives-bigger-biggest-more-interesting) to introduce the term of comparison; it is preceded by a comparative adjective or it's used with adverbs of quantity such as "more" or "less":

  > • Is "pretty nice" nicer *than* "nice"?
  >   
  >   • I ​spent more *than* I ​intended to.

Answer (score 3):

**Then** is for **time** or **ordering**
**Than** is for **comparing**

Maybe a way to remember it is

> **Then** and **time** and **order** have an **e**
>   **Than** and **compare** have an **a**

Comment: Um... compare also has an "e"...