# Comparison of height?

Tags: usage, comparative-constructions

If my height is more than my brother I say:

> I am taller then my brother

but if my height is less, which sentence is correct?

- > I am smaller then my brother
- > I am shorten then my brother
- > I am lower then my brother

Comment: "I am smaller than my brother" would hint at the fact  that you are smaller than him in every aspect, both height and weight in most circumstances.

Comment: "I am *shorter* then my brother", because *taller* is also specific to height.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I would point you to [Better then vs better than](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/80753/better-then-vs-better-than), as you should use *than*, not *then*.

As to your actual question:

I would say

```
I am shorter than my brother.
```

You could also say

```
I'm not as tall as my brother.
```

However, I would only use the second one in response to someone saying something like

```
You're so tall!
```

Otherwise, it would sound odd to me, though it's still grammatically correct.